# Hector: How to specify CQL version?

Tags: hector

I'd like to specify CQL Version when using Hector with Cassandra 1.1.5, specifically CQL 3.0.

How can I do that?

The answer to the question
[How to use CQL 3.0 with JDBC drivers or Hector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026207/how-to-use-cql-3-0-with-jdbc-drivers-or-hector)
was not useful.

Comment: Why do you want to specify CQL version?  CQL and Hector are two different API's.

Comment: CQL 3.0 is not ready yet and I'd like to use some enhancements in it..

Comment: Ahhh... you want to use a back-level of CQL with the latest Hector.

Answer (score 0):

For cassandra-jdbc, you can specify when creating the data source object.

```
CassandraDataSource cds = new CassandraDataSource(host, port, keyspace, user, password, "3.0.0")
```